# Commandline option depending on other option

Tags: bash, command-line

Suppose I have a script you pass the commandline options `--stable` and `--unstable`. When passing `--unstable`, the user should also be able to pass `--harmony` which enables features only present in the unstable version, so something like

```
./script --unstable --harmony
```

But what if the user does something like this:

```
./script --stable --harmony
```

Am I supposed to throw an error and stop execution? Or should I just ignore the `--harmony` flag?

Comment: That's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print a "warning" message saying that option is not valid and you will ignore it. I saw dozens of scripts doing that

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish this with the bash only `=~` operator, to test all arguments for the inclusion of both `stable` and `harmony`:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ "$@" =~ "stable" ]] && [[ "$@" =~ "harmony" ]] && {
    printf "\nerror: incompatible arguments provided.\n"
    printf "       arguments 'stable' and 'harmony' are mutually exclusive.\n\n"
    exit 1
}

printf "\n Only compatible arguments passed.\n\n"

exit 0
```

**usage:**

```
$ bash stblharm.sh --stable --harmony

error: incompatible arguments provided.
       arguments 'stable' and 'harmony' are mutually exclusive.

$ bash stblharm.sh --stable --something_else

 Only compatible arguments passed.
```